# How to avoid ']' of last value in array using Java?

Tags: java, arrays

I have string array output, but it contain `]`  with last value.

```
output=AA
output=BB
output=CC
output=DD]
```

How to avoid `]` of last `DD]` ?
I tried with,

```
int stringLength = ss.length();
String subString = ss.substring(0, stringLength-1);
System.out.println(subString);
```

But it avoid last value of all the elements. So how I need to do it?

Comment: How do you print the array? It's probably wrong right from the start, i.e. I assume you use `Arrays.toString()` and then split the result - not the way to go here.

Comment: what is your array actully contains and how you try to iterate please add more info about array(which u want to print)

Comment: The source code please.

Comment: @Thomas  Yes, you're correct. I got this result like that.

Answer (score 3):

In your answer to my ansumption in the comments you state that you're doing something like that:

```
String[] array = new String[]{"AA", "BB", "CC", "DD" };
String[] elems = Arrays.toString( array ).split(",");
for( String e : elems ) {
  System.out.println(e); //and here you try to get rid of the brackets
}
```

That seems like the wrong approach (without knowing your code, but with 99% certainty it is). Just loop over the elements directly:

```
String[] array = new String[]{"AA", "BB", "CC", "DD" };
for( String e : array ) {
  System.out.println(e);
}
```

Unless you're doing something completely different (which you didn't show us) there's no need to first use `Arrays.toString()` and then split again. Even if the array elements were not strings but something else `System.out.println()` would make use of the `toString()` method of the elements, just as `Arrays.toString()` would do.

**Edit**: according to your comment you get some string from some location that basically is in the form `[ [xxx/AA, xxx/BB], [xxx/CC] ]`. Using `String.split()` here is probably the wrong approach at all since you'll probably preserve the groupings etc.

Assuming the nesting stays the same in all circumstances, i.e. there is no additional grouping like `[ [ [ xxx/AA ], [xxx/BB] ] ]`, I'd suggest using a two step approach employing regular expressions:

```
Pattern groupsPattern = Pattern.compile("\\[([^\\[]+?)\\]");
Pattern contentPattern= Pattern.compile("/([^,/]+)\\s*(?:,|$)");

//Step 1: look for groups of text in square brackets, 
//i.e. look for "xxx, yyy" in "[xxx, yyy]"
Matcher groupsMatcher = groupsPattern.matcher( input );

while( groupsMatcher.find() ) {

  //Step 2: extract the values you're looking for from the group
  String groupContent = groupsMatcher.group(1);

  //here you could split on commas or use another pattern, which I'll do
  Matcher contentMatcher = contentPattern.matcher( groupContent );
  while( contentMatcher.find() ) {
    System.out.println( contentMatcher.group( 1 ) );
  }
}
```

Short breakdown of the expressions:

- `\[([^\[]+?)\]`

  - `[^\[]+?` means the shortest sequence of at least one character that is not a `[`
  - `(...)` captures the above as group 1 (0 is always the entire match)
  - `\[...\]` requires the group to be surrounded by square brackets
- `/([^,/]+)\s*(?:,|$)`

  - `([^,/]+)` means any sequence of at least one character which is not a comma or a slash and capture that as group 1
  - `\s*` means any sequence of whitespace (can be none)
  - `(?:,|$)` is a non-capturing group matching a comma or the end of the input
  - together it means: capture any squence of at least one character which is not a comma or a slash and which is preceded by a slash and followed by any whitespace and either a comma or the end of the input

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply.I used `[ [http://test/new/AA, http://test/new/BB] , [http://test/new/CC,http://test/new/DD, http://test/new/EE], [http://test/new/FF] ,[.....,.....] , [.....,......,.....] ]' and after split it by `,`  and  `/`  I used  `String my = output[output.length - 1];`  for take  `[AA,BB],CC,DD,EE],FF,......]'  as last value. So, I need to avoid `]`  in `BB] ,EE]`

Comment: @Emalka you might want to add that to your question since it's a cruical piece of information. And please add what you're trying to achieve in the end with that since I feel that there's a general flaw in the approach. As an example: wouldn't the brackets around `AA,BB` have a special meaning?

Comment: Thank you very much for your information and sharing knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to print out an array and are using Java 8 then the `StringJoiner` might help you to create an easily formated output.

```
String[] arr = {"output=AA", "output=BB", "output=CC", "output=DD"};
//the "\n" as parameter is used as a seperator for each array element here
StringJoiner joiner = new StringJoiner("\n"); 
for(String s : arr) joiner.add(s);
System.out.println(joiner);
```

Otherwise, if you don´t use java 8, you could just print the first element and append a line break with the next array item to a `String` to print the array properly formated:

```
String[] arr = {"output=AA", "output=BB", "output=CC", "output=DD"};
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
if(arr.length > 0) builder.append(arr[0]);
for (int i = 1; i<arr.length;++i) {
    builder.append("\n"+arr[i]); // append line break first to not have a linebreak as list char.
}
System.out.println(builder);
```

If you are using `Arrays.toString` you allways have to work around the fixed format that this method does use to print the `Object`, which will allways result in a few usages of `subString` and `replace`, which shouldn´t be the prefered way to print an array.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply

Answer (score 1):

This will resolve your issue in an efficient and easy way:

```
int stringLength = ss.length(); // this line can be deleted as you don't need it anymore here
String subString = ss.replace("]","");
System.out.println(subString);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply.It works , But I think this is not a good way  to solve it.

Comment: This replaces all the "]" found inside the string with an empty string. Is not this that you want? Or only the last character if it matches?

Comment: Just a this moment this is enough. But ,I think it may be a problem in future programming, if I will use this one. Thank you.

Comment: The middle line searches any occurrence for the character "]" and just deletes them. But if you want to change that rule in any way in the future than you will have to adjust your code. But this is the shortest way to do it, and an accurate way and free of bugs (as long as you want to remove any "]" included in your string).